# How to call a function that waits for return of API call (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

While learning Node.js and after some trial and error I have this working code that makes API calls to retrieve user records where each API call is dependent on the result of the previous API call.

```
const axios = require('axios')

var getDataById = async (config) => {
    var response = await axios(config);
    var userById = {};
    userById['userId'] = response.data["userId"];
    return(userById);
};

(async () => {
    var a = []; // array for storing user data
    var userId = '0001';

    var done = false; // false until user '0010' is reached

    while (!done) {
        url = "https://someurl.com/" + userId;

        var axiosconfig = {
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_TOKEN'
            }
        };

        var userDataById = await getDataById(axiosconfig);  
        a.push(userDataById);
        
        userId = userDataById['userId'];

        if (userId == '0010') { done = true }
    }

})()
```

How can I call this code from elsewhere in my program in such a way that

1. I can pass arguments to it...for example 'userId'
2. I can return 'a' to the calling function
3. the calling function waits for 'a' to be returned before continuing

TBH, I don't quite get how this works.

```
;(async () => {})()
```

Is there a better way of coding this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an async function and then await it.

The function definition will look like this

```
async function AddUser(userId)
```

You can return any variable and you call it like this:

```
await addUser('002')
```

await keyword make sure that the calling function waits for 'a' to be returned before continuing.

For your last question:

```
(async () => {})()
```

Is an arrow function.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Using async keyword + arrow function is a trick to allow you to create an async context and being able to use await. The two last `()` are used to direct call this function.